# Complexification of Banach space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I do have trouble understanding the following: Given is some (finite-dimensional) Banach space $B$ (with norm $\|\cdot\|_B$) with a $1$-unconditional basis. So

$\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i\|_B = \|\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| e_i\|_B$.

I am really only interested in finite dimensional spaces (I hope this should make it easier too), preferably something geometric. I guess $\ell_1^n$ is such a space with such a basis. I would like to understand how to turn this (or just $\ell_1^n$) into a complex Banach space $C$ (and how the $1$-unconditional basis comes into play). I am trying to follow [https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/~neerven/publications/papers/Positivity_98.pdf](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Eneerven/publications/papers/Positivity_98.pdf)

Already, the notation $|x|$ is used (for a Banach lattice). Is $|x| = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|e_i$ where $x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i$?

Can I just argue that $C$ consists of all vectors of the form $x + i\cdot y$, where $x,y \in B$?

The norm on $C$ can be given by $\|x + i\cdot y\|_C = \sup_{0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi}\|cos(\phi)x + sin(\phi)y\|_B$?

Are the linear functionals $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the form $a g_1(\cdot) + i\cdot b g_2(\cdot)$, where $g_1, g_2$ are linear functionals $B \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? Why do we need the $1$-unconditional basis?

Suppose I have $d_{BM}(B, \ell_2^n) \leq \sqrt{n}$ (where $d_{BM}$ is the Banach-Mazur distance). Once we complexify, can we still guarantee that $\exists \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\forall x_i \in \mathbb{C}: (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 \alpha_i)^{1/2} \leq \|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i\|_C \leq \sqrt{n}(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2 \alpha_i)^{1/2}$?

Any help is much appreciated!